Find out the points for which the map is a submersion.
I am following notations from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, $1^{\text{st}}$ edition.

Given $f: \mathbb{S}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y,z) = x + y$. Find out the points for which the map is a diffeomorphism.

Consider the atlas consisting of smooth charts $\{U_{i}^{+}, \phi_{i}^{+} \}$ and $\{U_{i}^{-}, \phi_{i}^{-} \}$ for $i = 1,2,3$ given by $\smash{U_{1}^{+} = \{ (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}): x_{1} > 0\}}$ and $\phi_{1}^{+} : U_{1}^{+} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) \mapsto (\hat{x}_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})$. Similar definitions for the other charts.
I want to compute the Jacobian matrix and then proceed. Can anyone help?

You probably should explain the $\hat{x}_1$ notation. Does this indicate that you've dropped that coordinate?

for this  :--
$$
f(x, y, z) = x + y.
$$
In the local coordinates of the chart ( \varphi_{+1}: U_{+1} \to \mathbb{R}^2 ), the coordinates are ( (x_2, x_3) ), and ( x_1 = \sqrt{1 - x_2^2 - x_3^2} ). So, the function becomes:
$$
f(x_2, x_3) = \sqrt{1 - x_2^2 - x_3^2} + x_2.
$$
The Jacobian matrix of ( f ) with respect to ( (x_2, x_3) ) is:
$$
J_f = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Compute the partial derivatives:
For ( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} ):
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = \frac{-x_2}{\sqrt{1 - x_2^2 - x_3^2}} + 1.
$$
For ( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3} ):
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3} = \frac{-x_3}{\sqrt{1 - x_2^2 - x_3^2}}.
$$
So, the Jacobian matrix becomes:
$$
J_f = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-x_2}{\sqrt{1 - x_2^2 - x_3^2}} + 1 & \frac{-x_3}{\sqrt{1 - x_2^2 - x_3^2}}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
To determine where ( f ) is a diffeomorphism, check when the Jacobian has full rank. The function fails to be a diffeomorphism at points where ( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = 0 ) and ( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3} = 0 ), or where the function is not injective (e.g., symmetric poles of ( S^2 )). Specifically, inspect cases like ( x_2 = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ) and ( x_3 = 0 ) and hope this helps .
